# Quiero extraer "Value" haciendo Web Scraping - Python

Tags: python, web, python-2.7, scrapy

```
item.add_xpath('id','//*[@id="search"]/div/input')
```

Quiero extraer el atributo "value" que está dentro de de la etiqueta div, lo que yo supongo es que debo añadir algo a esta línea de código, pero lo dejaré todo por si acaso, les agradecería su ayuda

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader


class StackItem(Item):
       tag = Field()
       user = Field()
       id = Field()


class StackCrawler(CrawlSpider):
  name = "CrawlerStack"
  allowed_domains = ['es.stackoverflow.com']
  start_urls = ['https://es.stackoverflow.com/users']


  rules={
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'page=')),
      Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'/users/'), callback = 'parse_items')
      }

  def parse_items(self, response):
      item = ItemLoader(StackItem(), response)
      item.add_xpath('user','//*[@id="user-card"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/h2/div/text()')
      item.add_xpath('tag','//*[@id="top-tags"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/text()')
      item.add_xpath('id','//*[@id="search"]/div/input')

      yield item.load_item()
```

Comment: Esto no deberias preguntarlo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar atributos dentro de una etiqueta, se usa el **@**. Tu ejemplo quedaría así. Al igual que has hecho en tu método `parse_items` con el id, pero en este caso, en vez de igualarlo a algo, simplemente lo quedas con el **@** indicando que eso es exactamente lo que quieres. Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
item.add_xpath('id','//*[@id="search"]/div/input/@value')
```